# How will full contact fighting against ocean waves harden all forms of combat training?

Tags: conditioning

I understand how conditioning our fists and shins against wood, concrete, and wood harden our martial art training for higher impact and force in our punches and kicks, but how will water, especially ocean waves harden our martial art?

Comment: Are you discussing movie scenes, or a particular school or style's teachings? Either is a valid question, but it's important for us to know what context to answer in.

Comment: Answer in relation to conditioning the human body using all martial arts training against ocean waves. How does this form of conditioning harden our martial art's?

Comment: In what sense do you mean "harden"?

Comment: In the sense of martial art conditioning of the human body during training...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it won't do much for physical conditioning of your limbs as would striking something solid since you are not likely to be creating the same microstresses that result in stronger bones. Also, it won't really do anything to improve your technique unless you're training to fight in the waves, and if so, you're better off actually training to fight another person instead of striking at the waves.

Where it might build some dividends is in mental endurance and balance recovery. Fighting to stay upright in crashing waves and shifting shore will provide an additional workout and help you to maintain your form in unpredictable circumstances. As a bonus, the cold water, likely salt-laden waves, and the force of them striking you, will help with mental fortitude, fighting even when you're uncomfortable. To some degree, it's the same reason some forms of meditation require you to meditate under a waterfall, to learn to shut out that discomfort.

That said, I suspect that, if this was ever commonly used, it was more in the spirit of military basic training, to break you down as a human being so that your instructor can assert dominance and rebuild you as a weapon. And today, it's likely used for marketing, an exotic training method available for extra fees or for those who have shown their loyalty.